# good practice to change page without reloading

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to change page but without any reloading
here's what I do:
AJAX:

```
 app.ajax.client.request = function(headers, path, method, queryObj, payload, cb) {
    // Set defaults
    headers = typeof(headers) == 'object' && headers !== null ? headers : {};
    path = typeof(path) == 'string' ? path : '/';
    method = typeof(method) == 'string' && ['POST','PUT','DELETE','GET'].indexOf(method.toUpperCase()) > -1 ? method.toUpperCase() : 'GET';
    queryObj = typeof(queryObj) == 'object' && queryObj !== null ? queryObj : {};
    payload = typeof(payload) == 'object' && payload !== null ? payload : {};
    cb = typeof(cb) == 'function' ? cb : false;
    // For each query string parameter sent, add it to the path
    let requestUrl = path + '?';
    let counter = 0;
    // Set the request url based on the query object
    for (let i in queryObj) {
      if (queryObj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        counter++
        if (counter > 1) {
          requestUrl += '&';
        }
        requestUrl += i + '=' + queryObj[i];
      }
    }
    // Form the http request as a JSON type
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open(method, requestUrl, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    // For each header sent, add it to the request
    for (let i in headers) {
      if (headers.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(i, headers[i]);
      }
    }

    // When the request comes back, handle the response
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      // Set the parameters that will be called back
      let readyState = xhr.readyState;
      let statusCode = xhr.status;
      let responseReturned = xhr.responseText;
      // Parse the response
      let parsedResponse = app.isJsonString(responseReturned);

      if (parsedResponse) { // If the response text is a JSON, callback parsedResponse, if not, callback the not parsed response instead
        cb(readyState, statusCode, parsedResponse);
      } else {
        cb(readyState, statusCode, responseReturned);
      }
    }
    // Send the payload as JSON
    let payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload);
    xhr.send(payloadString);
}
```

Client Requests:

```
app.changeToIndexPage = function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 if (!app.mainContainer.hasClass('index')) { 
  app.closePage(); // show a loading screen
  history.pushState({}, '', '/'); //Set the url to the index's url
  setTimeout(function() {
    app.ajax.client.request(undefined, 'public/request/index.txt', 'GET', undefined, undefined, function(readyState, statusCode, response) { // Get the request
      console.log(readyState);
      if (readyState < 3) { 
        app.preloader.addClass('loading');
      } else if (readyState == 4 && statusCode == 200) {
        app.navContainer.attr('class', app.navContainer.attr('class').replace(/index|project|about|contact/g, 'index'));
        setTimeout(function() {
          app.mainContainer.html(response);
        }, 500);
      }
    });
  }, 100);
}
```

}

So, for example: 
If I am not on the index page, and wanted to go to the index page, i can run the `changeToIndexPage` function, and the ajax will request the needed file and change the html element based on the needed action. The only problem that I had is, are there any better solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to take the approach of fetching pages with AJAX and slapping them into the document, which I wouldn't recommend in the first place, you should have a generalized function to do so.

That function should have a signature like `function navigate(path) { ... }`. It should add the history entry, fetch the appropriate document and insert it onto the page.

Then, you'll need to attach an event listener to catch `popState` events, so when the user presses the back button you retrieve the path from the history entry that was popped and pass it to `navigate()`.

Again, if you're looking to build an SPA I wouldn't recommend building it like this. One of the major benefits of SPAs are the performance gain from rendering your documents on the client, which this approach doesn't leverage. Consider using a component-based client-side rendering library like React or Angular.

Comment: thank you.. unfortunately I haven't learn any of those libraries.. so ill have to do what you said with the AJAX